# Where is the Border Style option in IB for a Text Field?

Tags: ios, xcode

Incredibly silly question I know, but in the past I have changed a 'Round Style' UITextField to a 'No Border Style' Text Field in Interface Builder in order to easily change the height of the box.
Now, when I come to do it, I can't for the life of me see where to change the border style!
I know it must be staring me in the face, but... can anyone show me the light?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look for the `Border Style` property in Attributes Inspector in Interface Builder.

[image: Xcode screenshot]

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm looking for, and that is what I have seen before, but I don't see that any more. How can I post a screen grab here? EDIT: Here is a link to a screen grab http://www.eyemack.co.uk/sg.jpg

Comment: It looks like you have the `Text Field` drop-down menu closed. Try clicking where it say `Text Field`.

Comment: Thank you, thank you! I was going mad. I knew it was obvious, just not that obvious! I'll go and stand in a corner somewhere.

Comment: This has been driving me nuts for the last 20-30 minutes. Thank you!